# Copy rows from different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, office-2007

How can I copy multiple rows in a worksheet and paste them further down, including any formatting like background colors and all the values already in the rows?

I tried using this snippet

```
Application.Worksheets("IPL").Select
Rows("6:9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Application.Worksheets("CMM").Select
Rows("13:13").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

But when I try to execute this, I get an application error. I tried some other examples but they don't seem to do the same what I want...

Any help?

Comment: This probably doesn't help you much but your code works on my machine as expected. (Excel 2003)

Comment: Well that's interesting... I'm using Excel 2007... Gonna add the Office-2007 tag so there's no confusion. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Did you try `Selection.Paste` and `Selection.PasteSpecial` ?

Comment: Okay, sorry - The code worked when everything was in the same sheet. But I actually need to copy between two sheets (adapted the question to that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simplified your code (the recorder's code is always full of unnecessary "selects") and it works fine, even across sheets !

```
Sheet1.Rows("5:6").Cut
Sheet2.Rows("18:19").Insert Shift:=xlDown
```